# Are "app vs. app" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm seeing a trend of questions that are asking for a comparison of features between two web apps.

Recent samples:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54390/studyblue-vs-anki
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54375/google-cloud-projects-vs-app-engine-apps

Are these questions on-topic here? Are they okay as long as they avoid the inevitable "which one should I get/use" question?

Comment: I'm not fond of these, but I have left comments on both to have the OP narrow down what they are asking about.  As is, I would accept them being too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apps v/s apps boil down to list v/s list and with the way web apps are revised so often, these lists get outdated soon enough.  I believe x v/s y are in the same league as "which should I use" questions and out of scope

Answer (score 5):

These would fit the "too broad" definition since you can list all kinds of features and functions against each other.

The also fall under the "unclear what you're asking" close reason since they're not giving us any idea why they're asking this question.

But the real reason is that they don't want to sign up for a free or limited trial and see if the web app will work for them, before they start asking if either one will do what task they're looking to get help with.

These all sound like recommendation questions either way, which are still off topic and out of scope.

Better for them to ask after they've tried one of the services and then detail what problem they're having exactly.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion as a web user I find this kind of questions useful, as I often need to decide which service to use. I don't buy Sathya's argument that these lists will get outdated soon, since that's also true for many answers that rely on some app's UI. However, I agree that it sound like recommendation questions, which I'm okay with but the this website's policy is not. I tend to ask and read those more open questions on Quora.